# Need Support with batch script to find, compress and move backup with daily schedule

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip, robocopy, del

I made a batch script to find and compress and move backup with daily schedule:

```
@echo off

robocopy C:\TempBackup  C:\TempBackup\X *.BAK* /w:0 /r:0 /np /fft /maxage:1 /maxlad:1

7z a -tzip X "X\*" -r

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/: " %%a in ('robocopy "|" . /njh ^| find ":"') do  set "CURRDATE=%%a%%b%%c" & set "CURRTIME=%%d%%e"

RENAME X.zip X_%CURRDATE%%CURRTIME%.zip

move /y C:\TempBackup\*.zip C:\Daily_Backup
rd /q  /s C:\TempBackup\X
del /q  C:\Tempbackup\*.BAK*

:stop
```

This script has only one problem that I only find 1 compressed file for the current day in Daily_Backup folder instead of 1 file for each day that the script runs.

Comment: Your method of obtaining the date and time is not robust enough and will not be accurate on other system locales. Here is a simple method: `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/: " %%a in ('robocopy "|" . /njh ^| find ":"') do  set "CURRDATE=%%a%%b%%c" & set "CURRTIME=%%d%%e"`

Comment: can u help me place this in my code?

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with your code. I would test it by running it, seeing whether the expected .zip appears in daily, then deliberatly create a dummy file in tempbackup and run again at leat 1 minute later. Observe results. If the second .zip appears as expected, I suspect that some other process is clearing the directory - possibly some other backup.

Comment: the solution is posted by Qwerty the problem was becuase of if this type of obtaining date. the script overwrite the past ones.